# Android/IOS Mobile application test automation : need recommendation on which framework to use?

Tags: java, appium, webdriver-io-v4

Appium with webdriver-io (javascript) or Appium with java, selenium is better for Mobile application testing?

I am testing a mobile application which runs in both Android and IOS. Need to use the browserstack service to run the test suit in different devices. At present unable to decide which framework should be used. Using webdriver-io will be convenient of not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have good understanding of JAVAScript then you can use Appium with webdriver-io.

2.If you have good understanding of JAVA then you can use Appium with JAVA and use page object with Page factory framework.

I do not suggest selenium for mobile automation testing. You can use appium for mobile automation as it has better method to deal with Native and WebView/Hybrid/Web apps/Angular based apps.

If you plan to use JAVA you can create single framework for iOS and Android using Page Factory annotations provided by Appium.